Python Launcher (py.exe) points to non-existent Python installation in AppData - how to fix?
When I run py --version on Windows, I get this error:
Unable to create process using '%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe --version': The system cannot find the file specified.

However, I have Python properly installed in C:\Program Files\Python312\ (confirmed by where python.exe).
Running ftype shows the Python Launcher is installed:
Python.ArchiveFile="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%L" %*
Python.CompiledFile="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%L" %*
Python.File="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%L" %*
Python.NoConArchiveFile="C:\Windows\pyw.exe" "%L" %*
Python.NoConFile="C:\Windows\pyw.exe" "%L" %*

And py -0p --list-paths shows:
 -V:3.12 *        %LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe

The launcher is looking for Python in my AppData folder (probably from an old installation), but Python is actually installed in Program Files. How can I fix this?

This issue occurs when Python launcher registration points to an old/removed Python installation. The problem is in the Windows Registry, where Python is registered in both HKEY_CURRENT_USER (user-specific) and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (system-wide) pointing to different locations.
You can verify this by checking both registry locations:
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore" /s
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python\PythonCore" /s

In my case:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER pointed to: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python312 (non-existent)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE pointed to: C:\Program Files\Python312 (correct location)

Solution:
Run these commands in an administrator CMD to remove the incorrect user-specific registration:
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore\3.12" /f
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore" /f

After this, the Python launcher will use the correct system-wide registration from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.
Verify the fix:

py --version should now work correctly
py -0p --list-paths should show the Program Files location
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore" /s should find nothing

Why this happens:
This typically occurs when you:

First install Python for the current user only (goes to AppData)
Later uninstall it
Then install Python for all users (goes to Program Files)

The old user-specific registry entries may remain, causing the Python launcher to look in the wrong location.
Alternative Solution:
If you prefer a fresh start, you could:

Uninstall Python completely
Delete any remaining Python folders in AppData
Reinstall Python with:

"Install for all users" checked (installs to Program Files)
"Add Python to PATH" checked



This will ensure clean registry entries.

I had forcibly removed Python3.8 and Python3.11 by deleting c:\Python3.8 and c:\Python3.11.  This worked for me: reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python\PythonCore\3.8" /f
reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python\PythonCore\3.11" /f  After that, py --list-paths listed the remaining Python installation.
